# Svelte/ Rollup Error “missing global variable name”

Tags: amazon-cognito, svelte, rollup

When I am importing  "AmazonCognitoIdentity" in my Routify project  I am getting "missing global variable name" error.

Error message:

```
 bundles src/main.js ÔåÆ dist\build\bundle.js...
LiveReload enabled
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
/js/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js (imported by src\pages\_components\Login.svelte)
(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
/js/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js (guessing 'amazonCognitoIdentity_min_js')
created dist\build\bundle.js in 2.7s
bundles src/sw.js ÔåÆ dist\sw.js...
created dist\sw.js in 1.6s
```

Following is my code

```
import { AmazonCognitoIdentity } from "/js/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js";

const authenticationData = {
    Username: userName,
    Password: password,
  };
  const authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(
    authenticationData
  );
  console.log(authenticationDetails);
  const poolData = {       
    UserPoolId: "xxxx”
    ClientId: "xxxxxxx", 
  };
  const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
  const userData = {
    Username: userName,
    Pool: userPool,
  };
  console.log(userData);
  const cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);

  cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
      const accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
      console.log(`on sucess: ${accessToken}`);
    },

    onFailure: function (err) {
      console.log(`onfailure: ${err}`);
      console.log(err);
    },
  });
```

and also I’ve linked the following file in _index.html

```
<script src="./js/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/amazon-cognito-auth.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.7.16.min.js"></script>
```

And the same process in working good in normal Html ad JavaScript files.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, you need to change the import statement so that it is relative:

```
import { AmazonCognitoIdentity } from "./js/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js";
```

I don't know where this file is, but you need to have `.` or `..` at the start of the location.

As I'm not an expert I yet cannot explain you why.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i amazon-cognito-identity-js
```

run this command first then update your import to this:

```
import { AmazonCognitoIdentity } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
```

Answer (score 0):

Flowing error is thrown after incorporating

```
npm i amazon-cognito-identity-js

import { AmazonCognitoIdentity } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
```

ERROR:

(!) Plugin node-resolve: preferring built-in module 'buffer' over local alternative at 'E:\ec-website\htx-pp-client\node_modules\buffer\index.js', pass 'preferBuiltins: false' to disable this behavior or 'preferBuiltins: true' to disable this warning

(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
buffer (imported by node_modules\amazon-cognito-identity-js\es\AuthenticationHelper.js, node_modules\amazon-cognito-identity-js\es\CognitoUser.js, node_modules\amazon-cognito-identity-js\es\CognitoJwtToken.js)

[!] Error: 'AmazonCognitoIdentity' is not exported by node_modules\amazon-cognito-identity-js\es\index.js, imported by src\pages_components\Login.svelte

**After adding this line to rollup.config.js**

```
rollup.external = ["AmazonCognitoIdentity", "amazon-cognito-identity-js"];
    rollup.output = {
      file: "dist/build/bundle.js",
      format: "umd",
      interop: "esModule",
      globals: {
        "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "AmazonCognitoIdentity",
      },
    };
```

The above error is gone. But at run time throws a new error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AmazonCognitoIdentity' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I got past this error by adding

```
import polyfills from "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills";
...
plugins: [
    polyfills(),
...
```

to my rollup.config.js

Answer (score -1):

```
import AmazonCognitoIdentity from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
```

Is your import correct?

Comment: Is this a question for clarification?